# Can we calculate this product explicitely?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Can we calculate this product explicitely?

$$q=∏_{j=1}^{n}(s_{j}+1)$$ where $s_{j}$ are real numbers.

Comment: That's as explicit as it's going to get.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis: So, we cannot simplify it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can imagine it as something of the form $$\prod_{j=1}^n s_j+\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\ne i}s_j+\sum_{\substack{\text{extended}\\\text{to all couples }\\(i,k)\subset\{1,...n\}}}\prod_{\substack{\text{extended}\\\text{to all }j\ne i,k}}s_j+\sum_{\substack{\text{extended}\\\text{to all triplets }\\(i,k,l)\subset\{1,...n\}}}\prod_{\substack{\text{extended}\\\text{to all } j\ne i,k,l}}s_j+...$$ $$...+\sum_{\substack{\text{extended}\\\text{to all } (n-2)-\text{tuples}\\(i_1,...,i_{n-2})\subset\{1,...n\}}}\prod_{\substack{\text{extended}\\\text{to all }j\ne i_1,...,i_{n-2}}}s_j+\sum_{j=1}^n s_j+1$$
where the (pairs, triplets,...) $n$-tuples are intended as non-ordered $n$-tuples of non-repeated indices.